# Modify / Add to TeX-Ligatures?

Tags: luatex, ligatures

I have finally caved and made the switch to LuaLaTeX, allowing me the proper use of UTF-8 everywhere and, of course, the use of `\usepackage{fontspec}`:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Numbers={OldStyle, Proportional}, Ligatures={TeX}]{Minion Pro}
```

My question is: Where are those common “TeX-Ligatures” defined, and how do I modify (read: add to) them? (I am not above hacking some core (Lua)(La)TeX files, mind you.)

-- becomes an n-dash, --- an m-dash: that is all good and proper, but there are a few others, most pressingly ... (three dots) becoming … (proper ellipsis).

Comment: The question "Where are those common “TeX-Ligatures” defined" is (most likely unintentionally) unclear: There are both "common ligatures" and "TeX ligatures"  -- and the terms aren't synonyms. Please clarify what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I guess I am referring to TeX-Ligatures and not “common” ligatures in the strict sense. When I enter -- (hyphen hyphen) in my document I am seeing – (endash) in the rendered PDF (created by LuaLaTeX), likewise --- (hyphen hyphen hyphen) becomes — (emdash). I would like to modify / add to that list.

Comment: Xelatex can use mapping files (search for `xelatex teckit`) which do regex replacement at font-level, for example, typing `puo` produces `ꁄ`. You can create your own maps. They are activated as a `fontspec` option. Alternatively, with utf-8 file format, unicode characters can be typed in (or input via the text editor) directly, `æ ¾ ą — ℉ ℊ`and so on. Alternatively again, for small volumes, the charcode method can be used: ^^^^^13153 produces , Egyptian hieroglyph G017 owl. Figure dash, en dash and em dash (`‒ – —`) are U+2012, U+2013, U+2014.

Comment: @Cicada That's an interesting approach, thanks for that. Too bad it's only available for XeTeX. (I already rely heavily on directly entered UTF-8 characters. I can certainly enter – (n-dash) and — (m-dash) directly, but there is no proper ellipsis in my keyboard layout.)

Comment: Mathematical symbols are not on the keyboard either. Why not use that same approach: define a macro 
`\newcommand\mydots{^^^^2026}`
and use it: `X \mydots Y`. Does it have to be Tex ligatures?

Comment: Does Minion Pro actually have the glyph?

Comment: Yes, Minion Pro has the glyph.

Comment: I support a bunch of authors. Some use –, some use -- : it doesn't matter, it renders the same way. I have yet to get them to use … instead of three dots. So, yes, it needs to be automated and as easy (read: “normal”) as possible for them.

Comment: `luaotfload-features.lua` defines the TeX "ligatures" (substitutions). The lua code in the answers would be more practical than patching a system file, I would imagine. If you are the central collation point, an auto-correct spell-check item would also work if your editor has such a feature. (Even a manual 'replace all', perhaps. On that point, expl3 has regex available, too.)

Answer (score 4):

It is not really visible, but if you copy&paste you can see that it works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\directlua{
fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature{
    name = "dotlig",
    type = "ligature",
    data = {
      [0x2026] = { ".", ".", "." },
    },
  }

}
\setsansfont{texgyreheros}[RawFeature=+dotlig;]
\setmainfont{texgyretermes}[RawFeature=+dotlig;]
\begin{document}
some text .... some text

\sffamily 

some text .... some text 
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. :-) Not sure what you mean by "not really visible", though. To my eye, there's a rather noticeable difference between the outputs of `...` and `.\kern0pt.\kern0pt.`

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to accomplish your objective. One of them -- I trust additional methods will be posted by other readers -- is to employ LuaTeX's `process_input_buffer` callback to replace all instances of `...`  with `\dots`. This approach ensures that text-style ellipses will be used in text mode and math-style ellipses will be used in math mode. If you want text-mode ellipses throughout the entire document, you should replace

```lua
  s = s:gsub ( '%.%.%.', '\\dots{}' )
```

with

```lua
  s = s:gsub ( '%.%.%.', '\\char"2026{}' )
```

in the Lua function shown below.

An advantage of this preprocessor-based approach is that you have to run the code just once, for the entire document. A potential disadvantage could be that you can't disable or enable this feature selectively for some fonts but not for others.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} % 'Ligatures={TeX,Common}' is enabled by default
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}[Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional}]
\setsansfont{Myriad Pro}[Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional}, Scale=MatchLowercase]

\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
function dots2ellipsis ( s ) 
  s = s:gsub ( '%.%.%.', '\\dots{}' ) 
  return s
end
```

```latex
\end{luacode}

\AtBeginDocument{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback ( 
   "process_input_buffer" , dots2ellipsis , "dots2ellipsis" )}}
   

\begin{document}
abc123 -- --- ... | $...$

\sffamily
abc123 -- --- ... | $...$
\end{document}
```