# What kinds of constructions are `, --, ---, and ``?

Tags: characters, active-characters

A couple of questions of a similar nature:

- We all know that `--` prints an endash, while `---` prints an emdash. But `-` is not an active character, right? So how does TeX process `--` and `---` and make them different from three ordinary dashes?
- `` prints a `“`. But ` is not an active character, right? So similarly to above, how is this processed?
- `'` *is* an active character, so I guess no issue there.
- The character ` plus some character token prints the character number (or whatever the right term is) for that token, as seen e.g. in catcode assignments. What kind of construction is this? Can I change this to some other character?
- Is there a way to print ` on TeX.SX? Typing ``` doesn’t work.

Comment: These are ligatures like `ff` or `fl`. I'm pretty sure this has been asked before…

Comment: @cgnieder Not all of the questions, I think.

Comment: See [What is ` (backtick) used for?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/404649/82917) and [How does “\char`” work?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/402531/82917) for the fourth question. Note that the backtick does not always give a number: it works only when TeX *expects* a number.

Comment: When I asked a similar question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/569020/modify-add-to-tex-ligatures I learned that they were simply called Tex ligatures.

Comment: The questions about ligatures are duplicate; the last question belongs to the Meta site.

Comment: For the last question, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3150.

Comment: `'` is not an active character despite your 3rd bullet.